# type casting of unsigned long long to long double

Tags: c

This is the expression

```
 return (pow(10, ptr[i].nf / 5.0L) + (ptr[i].busy_time /ptr[i].active_time)
        * pow(2,pow(10,(long double)ptr[i].nf / 10.0L) - pow(10,(long double)min_nf / 10.0L)));
```

`active_time` and `busy_time` are of type `unsigned long long` which i have type casted to `long double`, why is the whole calculation it returning a `nan` value

Comment: what are all of the other things?

Comment: all others are long double only

Comment: "nan" is C. it stands for not a number

Comment: is `active_time` zero? Would be useful if you printed all the variables used in the equation, so that we can see where your unexpected result comes from :)

Comment: Break this huge expression into pieces, assign the values of such pieces to intermedtiate (debug)-variables, compile with symbols, run the code in a debugger and inspect such debug-variables and you surely get enlightened. Alternativly to using a debugger just print out the debug-variables.

Comment: It is impossible to tell with the code posted. You are basically asking "why is x of the value nan, given the expression x = y + z".

Comment: Perhaps `ptr[i].active_time` is zero, or `ptr[i].nf` is substantially greater than 10 (so you have `2^(10^x)` which will overflow when x is even quite small).

Comment: Survey data from wlan2
        frequency:                      2412 MHz        channel =1
        noise:                          -95 dBm
active time = 14401768338470469632
nf = -12        ,busytime = 216600243319        activetoime = 0 min_nf =96
interference = -nan

Comment: nf = -12        ,busytime = 7.89551e-4940       activetoime =0.66613e-15       min_nf =-95
interference = -nan